# COUNT и total c двух колонок

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

Задача - необходимо подсчитывать и выводить COUNT с двух колонок, в которых находятся числа от 1 до 30. Имеем  следующий код

```
$query="SELECT nam1 , COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex WHERE nam1 > 0 GROUP BY nam1 ";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
      echo $row['nam1'];
      echo '&nbsp;';
      echo $row['total'];
      echo '<br>';
    }
```

Получаем результат

```
1 = 714
10 = 227
11 = 215
12 = 187
...
```

Вместо одной колонки nam1 нужно сделать что-то типа total nam1 + total nam2
И выглядело это так 1 = "714(с первой колонки)+...(со второй колонки)"

Comment: COUNT(nam1)+COUNT(nam2) AS total, не?

Comment: Вообще count() считает строки, а не колонки. что такое nam2, как бы вы посчитали это количество, если бы хотели вывести только его ?

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент реализовал банальным методом:

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT nam3 , COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex
    WHERE nam3 > 0 GROUP BY nam3 
    ORDER BY nam3+ 0 ASC
    ";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {   
      $headers3 .= "<th> {$row['nam3']} </th>";
      $col3 .= "<td><div class='{$row['nam3']}_totalprice'> {$row['total']} </div> </td>";
    }
    echo "<table><tr>$headers3</tr><tr>$col3</tr></table>";
    ?>

      <?php
    $query="SELECT nam4 , COUNT(*) AS total FROM lottoindex
    WHERE nam4 > 0 GROUP BY nam4 
    ORDER BY nam4+ 0 ASC
    ";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {   
      $headers4 .= "<th> {$row['nam4']} </th>";
      $col4 .= "<td><div class='{$row['nam4']}_totalprice'> {$row['total']} </div> </td>";
    }
    echo "<table><tr>$headers4</tr><tr>$col4</tr></table>";
    ?>
```

....
И так шесть раз, обернув все это дело в див с display:none далее с помощью js

```
<td>
            <script>    
               var sum = 0;
               $('.1_totalprice').each(function(){
               sum += parseFloat($(this).text());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
               });  
               document.write(sum);
            </script>
          </td>
          <td>
            <script>    
               var sum = 0;
               $('.2_totalprice').each(function(){
               sum += parseFloat($(this).text());  // Or this.innerHTML, this.innerText
               });  
               document.write(sum);
            </script>
          </td>
```

и так 49 раз =) вставив ручками  от 1 до 49 ... Тоесть каждой переменнойс помощью того же цикла выдал уникальный клас и по нему просумирова со всех полей. 
Хотя реально это не вариант как можно оптимизировать данное "рукоблудство"

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when nam1 is null then nam2
            when nam2 is null then nam1
            else nam1 end as nam,
       case when nam1 is null then '0 + ' || s2.total
            when nam2 is null then s1.total || ' + 0'
            else s1.total || ' + ' || s2.total end as total
from (SELECT nam1, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam1 > 0
      GROUP BY nam1) s1
    FULL JOIN
      (SELECT nam2, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam2 > 0
      GROUP BY nam2) s2
    on s1.nam1 = s2.nam2
```

Попробуйте такой запрос, например.
Он соединяет 2 таблицы с nam1 и nam2.

---

Вариант для MySQL:

```
select case when nam1 is null then nam2
            when nam2 is null then nam1
            else nam1 end as nam,
       case when nam1 is null then concat('0 + ', s2.total)
            when nam2 is null then concat(s1.total, ' + 0')
            else concat(s1.total, ' + ', s2.total) end as total
from (((SELECT nam1, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam1 > 0
      GROUP BY nam1) s1
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT nam2, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam2 > 0
      GROUP BY nam2) s2
    on s1.nam1 = s2.nam2) t1

      UNION

     ((SELECT nam1, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam1 > 0
      GROUP BY nam1) s1
    RIGHT JOIN
      (SELECT nam2, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM lottoindex
      WHERE nam2 > 0
      GROUP BY nam2) s2
    on s1.nam1 = s2.nam2) t2)
```

Comment: Не вышло, ошибко не выдало но и результаты не показало =(

Comment: @Жека какая у вас бд? в mysql не работает `full join`, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: mysql  .... есть варианты учитывая это?

Comment: @Жека у вас столбцы nam1 и nam2 в одной таблице? покажите пример структуры таблицы.

Comment: table "lottoindex" column "col1" "nam1" "nam2" "nam3" "nam4" "nam5" "nam6" да в одной. Все колонки заполнены, значения nall не может быть

Comment: @Жека `null` здесь используется для соединения, на случай, если в nam1 есть значения, которых нет в nam2, и наоборот. Подправил ответ для mysql, проверить не могу, должно работать.

Comment: Не удалось выдало пустое поле

Comment: @Жека вы запросы проверяйте в консоли MySQL что бы видеть ошибки. потому как у себя в php коде вы проверок на ошибки и их печать не делаете, а надо бы ...

Comment: @Denis Усложняете ... `select nam, sum(cnt1), sum(cnt2) from (select nam1 as nam, count(1) as cnt1, NULL as cnt2 ....  UNION ALL select nam2, NULL, count(1)  ... ) A group by nam`

Comment: @Mike Чего то тут явно не хватает...

Comment: @Жека Ну так я многоточия поставил, там нормальные запросы пишите, каждый из которых нужные количества получает. Собственно у вас в вопросе данных для нормального решения то же не содержится, структуру таблицы и образца данных вы не привели, на мой вопрос как бы вы получали количества по nam2 не ответили ... из чего ответ то нормальный строить ... Да и какой смысл ответ писать, если вы его даже проверить не сможете, ибо сообщения об ошибках не выводите. А без нормально созданной таблицы, такой как у вас проверить у себя его невозможно. в sqlfiddle пример бы сделали ...